# How can calendar event have all email addresses omitted and AttendeesOmitted flag set to true?

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

We are using google-api-dotnet library version 1.9.1 and lately we've been receiving events which are missing all the email addresses of attendees, participants and organizer. Status can be "confirmed" and strangely "AttendeesOmitted" flag is set to true. We are not really sure how to handle these events and how it's even logical to omit all the emails which are obligatory always?

```
Dim getRequest = Me._CalendarService.Events().Get(email, entryId)
        getRequest.TimeZone = "UTC"

        Dim calendarEvent1 = getRequest.Execute()
```

We are not setting any other flags to the request. I just noticed that the event is marked as private. I tested this with Google REST API and I can see organizer email and participant email even though I'm not organizer and visibility is private with all access rights(modify) removed and I'm calling API with participant user.

Comment: could you post your code please.

Comment: While retreiving events if maxAttendees specified in the request is less than the number of invitees in the event, then attendeesOmitted will be set to "TRUE" and attendes will be omitted from events representation. I tested this scenario. You can also refer to this link https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events

Comment: We are not setting maxAttendees it's default value is null so it should not affect this?

Comment: Are the guest lists for these events really long?

Comment: guest lists are usually couple of users. This started to happen during this autumn, we haven't been able to reproduce the issue though.